# How to get max value from a nested json

Tags: javascript

have json object of which I would like to get the max value of showstopinfo :

```
var data = [{
  "info": [
    {
      "ticketinfooo": {
        "showstopinfo": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "ticketinfooo": {
        "showstopinfo": 6
      }
    }

  ]
}, {

  "info": [
    {
      "ticketinfooo": {
        "showstopinfo": 22
      }
    },
    {
      "ticketinfooo": {
        "showstopinfo": 23
      }
    }

  ]
}]
```

I`ve just written the code below but it return NAN value:

```
var max = Math.max(...data.map(e => e.info.map(x => x.ticketinfooo.stoppinfoo.showstopinfo)))
console.log(max)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: The issue here is that the structure of your `data` array is not consistent. In the first object of the `data` array, `showstopinfo` is nested inside `stoppinfoo`, which is nested inside `ticketinfooo`. However, in the second object of the `data` array, `showstopinfo` is directly inside `ticketinfooo`, without `stoppinfoo`.

When your code tries to access `x.ticketinfooo.stoppinfoo.showstopinfo` for the second object, it returns `undefined` because `stoppinfoo` does not exist in the second object. When `Math.max()` tries to compare numbers with `undefined`, it returns `NaN`.

Comment: I suppose the incorrect data structure is in the post only, otherwise OP can't get `NaN`.

Comment: Yes, It was my fault, now the structure of data array is consisten

Comment: what is a "nested JSON"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `map()` on the outer array and *also* the inner `info` array. From there you'll have a 2d array which you'll need to flatten.

Here's a working example:

```js
var data = [{info:[{ticketinfooo:{showstopinfo:1}},{ticketinfooo:{showstopinfo:6}}]},{info:[{ticketinfooo:{showstopinfo:22}},{ticketinfooo:{showstopinfo:23}}]}];

var values = data.map(d => [...d.info.map(i => i.ticketinfooo.showstopinfo)]).flat();
var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
console.log(max)
```

Comment: I edited the above answer to cater for the updated input data the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `.flat()` at the end of your array. Also `x.ticketinfooo.stoppinfoo.showstopinfo` should be `x.ticketinfooo.showstopinfo`.

```
Math.max(...data.map(e => e.info.map(x => x.ticketinfooo.showstopinfo)).flat()) 
>>> 23
```